# Two identical (?) approaches using map_dbl() leading to different outputs in R, but why?

Tags: r

For a coding challenge on a learning platform, i was asked to compute sampling errors for 100 different sample sizes. My approach does not generate the same values as the provided solution does, but I do not understand why - to me, they seem to be doing the same thing. Or am I missing anything? I am a coding beginner, so it is entirely possible that I am missing something!

**Here is the setup for the challenge:**

```
set.seed(4)
parameter  <-  mean(houses$SalePrice) # parameter value = 180796.1
sample_sizes  <-  seq(from = 5, by=29, length.out=100)
```

```
library(purrr)
```

**Here is my approach:**

```
sample_means <- map_dbl(sample_sizes, function(x) mean(sample(houses$SalePrice, size=x)))
sampling_errors_a <- parameter - sample_means
```

**Here is the provided solution:**

```
sampling_errors <- map_dbl(sample_sizes, function(x) parameter - mean(sample(houses$SalePrice, size=x)))
```

When I run `identical(sampling_errors_a, sampling_errors)`, R keeps returning FALSE. I looked at the values of both vectors and, in fact, they are totally different.

I would love to understand why the 2 approaches do not arrive at the same solution. If somebody had a moment to spare to explain, I would very much appreciate it. Thank you to all of you in advance!

Comment: you need to set seeds when doing random number generation

Comment: Most likely this is a case of floating-point precision limits.  Take a careful read of `?identical` .   But it would be helpful if you provide the source of `houses`  and of `map_dbll`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: the clue that this is *not* a FAQ 7.31 issue is that the OP says the results are "totally different"

Comment: @BenBolker  I'd agree except that one never knows what a new poster means by "totally"  :-)

Comment: @BenBolker: guys, you are right - "totally different" is not precise. I've only been coding for a few months, so I lack the experience which is reflected in my poor statement. Nonetheless,  I will try to do better in the future and I appreciate that you all were so helpful - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** you have to reset the seed by running `set.seed(4)` again before you evaluate a different approach. (You don't need to run `set.seed()` *immediately* before the new code, but you need to make sure that the code between `set.seed()` and your new approach doesn't do anything that calls the pseudo-random number generator ...)

In this particular case, that will give you identical results. However, **in general** you should get in the habit of using `all.equal()` instead of `identical()` to compare floating-point results, as very subtle differences in computation [can lead to small differences in results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558).

I've shortened some of the variable names etc. and used a randomly generated example instead of your house-price variable.

```r
set.seed(101)                                                                                                                              
vals <- rnorm(1000)                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                           
set.seed(4)                                                                                                                                
p0 <- mean(vals)                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                           
## this is a weird specification - results in non-integer sample sizes ... ??
##  but if that's really what your instructor said to do, I guess you should use it                                                              
s <- seq(5, 29, length.out = 100)                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                           
m <- purrr::map_dbl(s, ~ mean(sample(vals, size = .)))                                                                                     
result_1 <- p0 - m                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                           
set.seed(4)  ## THIS IS THE KEY STEP                                                                                                       
result_2 <- purrr::map_dbl(s, ~ p0 - mean(sample(vals, size = .)))                                                                         
                                                                                                                                           
identical(result_1, result_2) ## TRUE                                                                                                      
all.equal(result_1, result_2) ## TRUE
```

Comment: Well put  ....  I would recommend even simpler approach:  `set.seed(number)` then  `foo <- sample(houses$SalePrice, size=x)`  , followed by sticking `foo` into the subsequent analysis equations.

Comment: Thank you so much to all of you for taking the time to review and answer my question, I really appreciate it! Of course, I need to make sure that both approaches use the same set.seed() specifications - this should have occurred to me! It totally resolved the issue. Moreover, it I am relieved that my approach was not entirely wrong, though not as efficient as the solution. Again, thank you all so much!

Comment: IMO there's barely any difference between your solution and the recommended one